# Do for Each Element of a Vector What I Do for Just One in R

Tags: r, for-loop

The bellow `R` code does the following algorithm in steps:

1. Simulate `ARIMA(1,1,0)` time series (line 1 to line 9)
2. Determine the vector of block sizes to be used (line 19)
3. Choose the first element (2) of the vector (line 20)
4. Split the time series into blocks of equal size of 2 (line 22)
5. Resample each block at random 1000 times (line 25)
6. Rearrange the resampled series into time series data (line 27)
7. Obtain the RMSE of the resampled time series (line 29)
8. Loop over step 5 to step 7 ten(10) times and obtain the average value of the 10 RMSE (line 30 to line 32)

```
# simulate arima(1,1,0)
library(forecast)
set.seed(100)
wn <- rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1)
ts <- wn[1:2]
for (i in 3:10){
  ts<-arima.sim(n=10,model=list(ar=-0.7048,order=c(1,1,0)),start.innov=4.1,n.start=1,innov=wn)
}
ts <-ts[-1]

# write the function for RMSE
rmse <- function(x) {
  m <- auto.arima(x)
  acu <- accuracy(m)
  acu[1, 2]
}
#
t<-length(ts)# the length of the time series
li <- seq(n-2)+1 # vector of block sizes to be 1 < l < n (i.e to be between 1 and n exclusively)
l<- li[1]# first block size
m <- ceiling(t / l) # number of blocks
blk<-split(ts, rep(1:m, each=l, length.out = t)) # divides the series into blocks
singleblock <- vector() #initialize vector to receive result from for loop
for(i in 1:10){
  res<-sample(blk, replace=T, 1000) # resamples the blocks
  res.unlist<-unlist(res, use.names = F) # unlist the bootstrap series
  tsunlist<-ts(res.unlist) # turns the bootstrap series into time series data
  # use the RMSE function
  RMSE <- rmse(tsunlist)
  singleblock[i] <- RMSE # Assign RMSE value to final result vector element i
}
singleblock
mean(singleblock)
```

I want the `R` program to go back to **step 3 line 19** to choose the second element in the vector, continue to step 4 up to step 8 to write the average RMSE. Go back to step 3 again to choose the next element of the vector and do as before until the element of the vector is exhausted.

**I want my expected result to be arranged in table form as:**

```
# 2    3     4    5    6    7    8    9 
# ... ...  ...   ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I properly understood that you were attempting to do repeat the steps across the elements in vector `li`. There is likely a more efficient way to accomplish the same thing especially for large n values. I picked n = 5. I created a matrix 'RSMEblk' to store the block means into. You could chose to create a list to store the single blocks if you needed those values as well.

```
# simulate arima(1,1,0)
library(forecast)
set.seed(100)
wn <- rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1)
ts <- wn[1:2]
for (i in 3:10){
     ts<-arima.sim(n=10,model=list(ar=-0.7048,order=c(1,1,0)),start.innov=4.1,n.start=1,innov=wn)
}
ts <-ts[-1]

# write the function for RMSE
rmse <- function(x) {
     m <- auto.arima(x)
     acu <- accuracy(m)
     acu[1, 2]
}
#
n<-5 # max block size
t<-length(ts)# the length of the time series
li <- seq(n-2)+1 # vector of block sizes to be 1 < l < n (i.e to be between 1 and n exclusively)

RMSEblk<-matrix(nrow = 1, ncol = length(li))#vector to store block means
colnames(RMSEblk)<-li
for (b in 1:length(li)){
    l<- li[b]# block size
    m <- ceiling(t / l) # number of blocks
    blk<-split(ts, rep(1:m, each=l, length.out = t)) # divides the series into blocks
    singleblock <- vector() #initialize vector to receive result from for loop
    for(i in 1:10){
        res<-sample(blk, replace=T, 1000) # resamples the blocks
        res.unlist<-unlist(res, use.names = F) # unlist the bootstrap series
        tsunlist<-ts(res.unlist) # turns the bootstrap series into time series data
        # use the RMSE function
        RMSE <- rmse(tsunlist)
        singleblock[i] <- RMSE # Assign RMSE value to final result vector element i
    }
#singleblock
RMSEblk[b]<-mean(singleblock) #store into matrix
}
```

The output becomes for n = 5

```
> RMSEblk
             2        3         4
[1,] 0.4671414 0.792863 0.4482386
```

Comment: If you like my question, do it a tumb up